# Как сделать так, чтобы сообщение с фото изменялось при нажатии на инлайн кнопку?

Tags: telegram, aiogram

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button6')
async def process_callback_button1(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    workfile = open('work.jpg', 'rb')
    await call.answer()
    await call.bot.send_photo(call.from_user.id, workfile, 'asd')
```

есть такой код. он просто отправляет картинку вместе с текстом. как сделать так, чтобы изначальное сообщение (без картинки) изменилось на это сообщение (с картинкой). как при использовании функции message.edit_text.

пытался сделать через эту самую функцию - не получилось. я думаю что для редактирования сообщений с изображениями нужна другая функция, но я не знаю какая

UPD: попробовал сделать вот так, пишет ошибку TypeError: process_callback_button1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'photo'

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button6')
async def process_callback_button1(call: types.CallbackQuery, photo: types.InputMediaPhoto):
    workfile = open('work.jpg', 'rb')
    await call.answer()
    await bot.edit_message_media(workfile, caption="New text", media=photo)
```

Comment: На что вы меняете?

Comment: Неправильно написал вопрос. Обновил, теперь все верно

Comment: Зачем вы добавили photo в параметры функции? Уберите его

Comment: все та же ошибка

Comment: Вы хотите менять одну картинку на другую?

Comment: Нет. У меня есть изначально сообщение (только текст), под этим сообщением есть инлайн кнопка. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы когда я нажимал на кнопку, то изначальное сообщение заменялось на сообщение с картинкой.

Comment: В таком случае просто удалите сообщение и отправьте новое

Comment: а есть способ именно изменить старое сообщение? или только отправлять новое?

Comment: Проблема в том что и на что вы пытаетесь изменить. В вашем случае только как я писал выше